# Custom -vsdoc.js intellisense not displaying

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have a custom javascript called chris-vsdoc.js

Im trying to get Visual Studio 2010 intellisense to display the sayHello function

```
var chris = new chris();
function chris() {
    this.sayHello = function (message) {
        /// <summary>
        /// Shows a message in a dialog box, with an OK button.
        /// </summary>  
        /// <param name="message">
        /// message - the message to display
        /// </param>
    }

 }
```

My other .js files have a reference in them list this

```
/// <reference path="../chris-vsdoc.js" />
```

Any ideas how to get intellisense working?

Is there something Im missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use virtual root (`~/`) paths in the Intellisense reference directive, which has worked best for me in the past, e.g.:

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/chris-vsdoc.js" />
```

Also, you can mark up your actual `chris.js` file with the VSDoc comments and reference that, rather than needing to have a separate VSDoc.  Minification will strip out all the VSDoc information anyway since it's just a regular JavaScript comment that begins with another `/`.

I usually end up with a central `main.js` (named based on the project, not "main"), and then several `main.namespace.js` files that eventually all get combined into one (with "main").  `main.js` has a `/// <reference />` to each of the `main.namespace.js` files and then each of those has a single `/// <reference />` back to `main.js`.

Using that approach, I get correct, VSDoc-driven Intellisense for the entire group of files in any one of them.

Comment: @Chris Make sure your `/// <ref`'s are at the top of the file. If anything else comes first, they won't work.